# runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Tags: c++, runtime-error, overflow

When I execute below code when value of parameter n is 2147483647, I get error(*runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'*) from if phase. But "INT_MAX" is printed. Can you explain why I am getting this error?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int myFunct(int n) {
        if (n == INT_MAX) cout << "INT_MAX" << endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: `2147483647` is the value of `INT_MAX` if `int` is a 32 bit type. The expression `2147483647 + 1` causes an overflow of a 32 bit `int` (which is Undefined Behavior in C++). I would expect the same for `INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: The shown code cannot be executed because there is no `main`. The error that you get indicates that you have an expression like `n + 1` for which `n` is `2147483647`, but there is no such an expression shown in the code, so it is unlikely that the error happens in the given code (`if (n == INT_MAX)` is not the origin for the error).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full compilable code and the full compiler output

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. This code is running on leetcode.com, so I don't have to write main(), and leetcode use C++17 standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the snippet provided:

```
#include <iostream>

class Solution {
public:
    int myFunct(int n) {
        if (n == INT_MAX)
            std::cout << "INT_MAX" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Solution s;
    // Here we are passing +1 than INT_MAX value
    // (i.e. overflowing 4-bytes integer)
    s.myFunct(INT_MAX + 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to store values beyond the limit of `INT_MAX` will result an overflow and cause Undefined Behavior in runtime. **Since it's UB, it might be working for you, but not for us.**

That is, my TDM-GCC 9.2.0 compiler produced the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21:23: warning: integer overflow in expression of type 'int' results in '-2147483648' [-Woverflow]
   21 |     s.myFunct(INT_MAX + 1);
      |
```